# How we can trigger a REST API after successful resource creation in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudsearch

I am creating an AWS cloudsearch domainfrom terraform, after successful creation of this domain, I need to trigger one REST API. can anyone have idea how we can do this in terraform ?

sample Terraform code :

```
   resource "aws_cloudsearch_domain" "example" {
  name = "example-domain"

  scaling_parameters {
    desired_instance_type = "search.medium"
  }

  index_field {
    name            = "headline"
    type            = "text"
    search          = true
    return          = true
    sort            = true
    highlight       = false
    analysis_scheme = "_en_default_"
  }

  index_field {
    name   = "price"
    type   = "double"
    search = true
    facet  = true
    return = true
    sort   = true
  }
}

  
resource "aws_cloudsearch_domain_service_access_policy" "example" {
  domain_name = aws_cloudsearch_domain.example.id

  access_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"search_only",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal":"*",
    "Action":[
      "cloudsearch:search",
      "cloudsearch:document"
    ]
  }]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: What "resource"? Your question is unclear and lacks details. Do you have any TF code to show?

Comment: updated the description in question

Comment: Have you observed whether TF completes creation of the cloudsearch domain when its fully provisioned or ready to use, or it just initiate the creation and moves to other resources?

Comment: Without specifics it's hard to make a more useful statement than: Terraform models API requests using resource types implemented in providers, so if you want Terraform to make an additional API request then the typical answer would be to either find a provider which already offers a resource type that can make the request you need, or to write your own provider which can encapsulate what's needed for your use-case.